# jQuery selector problem

Tags: jquery

I have problem with sliding up/down a class in my project and would appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="left" style="width:100%;"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
<div class="regler">Regler</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("input.text").focus(function () {
     $(this).animate({width:'80%'},'slow',function(){
         $(this).next('input.btn').fadeIn('Slow');
     });
     $(this).next(".regler").slideDown('Slow');
});
$("input.text").blur(function () {
     $(this).next('input.btn').fadeOut('Slow',function(){
         $(this).prev().animate({width:'100%'},'slow');
     });
     $(this).next(".regler").slideUp('Slow');
});
```

CSS:

```
.regler {
 display: none;  
}

input.btn {
 display: none;  
}
```

The jQuery is located after the HTML in scripts tags.

`$(this).next(".regler").slideDown('Slow');` and `$(this).next(".regler").slideUp('Slow');` is the only rows that doesn't work.

Thanks for answers, Victor.

Comment: The CSS was missing, you can see the update here: http://jsfiddle.net/U2MPy/1/

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize the `regler` should slide up :P

Comment: The final and fixed effect works nicley and its seen here http://jsfiddle.net/jzujY/

Comment: Kobi, I figured that out, but I diden't now about the siblings...

Comment: Here's a version with many input fields: http://jsfiddle.net/jzujY/1/ . I was wrong about `siblings`, it seems. Another point to consider: it doesn't work well if the user is on the input fields, and then clicks `Tab` - the button gets hidden. You may want to handle its focus and blur as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` is only looking for the immediate next element. Since `this` is the textbox in your context, it has no next `.regler`. If these tags are wraped in a parent container, try this:

```
$(this).siblings(".regler").slideUp('Slow');
```

Or, if you have many sets if inputs:

```
$(this).next().next(".regler").slideUp('Slow');
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for a simple and quick answer :)